# Как создать js код на несколько якорных ссылок?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть html-код, в котором несколько якорных ссылок, вверху фиксированная менюшка с фиксированной высотой. Нужно сделать js-код, который при использовании одной из якорных ссылок будет переносить не на сам якорь, а на 140 пикселей ниже...

Comment: как я понимаю нужно сначала создать массив  var arrYakor = [], а как в него вписать все id?

Comment: может так? var arrYakor = [ #-homepage, #services, #contact]

Comment: покажите ваш HTML код меню

Comment: Я правильно понял нужно что-то подобное https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Со второго раза вопрос понял. Js тут не нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал для наглядности: данный код делает плавный скролл к якорю, но останавливается на 100 пикселей выше.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
       'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 100
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
       window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.one {
 height: 1000px;
 background: tomato;
}
.two {
 height: 1000px;
 background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#one">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="one" id="one">1</div>
<div class="two" id="two">2</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать без скриптов:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: silver;
}

section {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: -2rem;
}

section:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#s1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#s2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#s3">Section 3</a>
  <a href="#s4">Section 4</a>
  <a href="#s5">Section 5</a>
</nav>
<section id="s1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Есть html-код, в котором несколько якорных ссылок, вверху фиксированная менюшка с фиксированной высотой. Нужно сделать js-код, который при использовании одной из якорных ссылок будет переносить не на сам якорь, а на 140 пикселей ниже...</p>
</section>
<section id="s2">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Есть html-код, в котором несколько якорных ссылок, вверху фиксированная менюшка с фиксированной высотой. Нужно сделать js-код, который при использовании одной из якорных ссылок будет переносить не на сам якорь, а на 140 пикселей ниже...</p>
</section>
<section id="s3">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Есть html-код, в котором несколько якорных ссылок, вверху фиксированная менюшка с фиксированной высотой. Нужно сделать js-код, который при использовании одной из якорных ссылок будет переносить не на сам якорь, а на 140 пикселей ниже...</p>
</section>
<section id="s4">
  <h1>Section 4</h1>
  <p>Есть html-код, в котором несколько якорных ссылок, вверху фиксированная менюшка с фиксированной высотой. Нужно сделать js-код, который при использовании одной из якорных ссылок будет переносить не на сам якорь, а на 140 пикселей ниже...</p>
</section>
<section id="s5">
  <h1>Section 5</h1>
  <p>Есть html-код, в котором несколько якорных ссылок, вверху фиксированная менюшка с фиксированной высотой. Нужно сделать js-код, который при использовании одной из якорных ссылок будет переносить не на сам якорь, а на 140 пикселей ниже...</p>
</section>
```

Comment: интересный вариант, но как быть, если у `section` есть `background` - он ведь будет наплывать на верхний блок?

Comment: @lexxl, предлагаю привести пример, задать с ним отдельный вопрос и дать ссылку. Потому что, во-первых, не будет, во-вторых не на, а под, что проявится только при прозрачном фоне заголовка, а в-третьих, как ты представляешь скролл, чтобы он не затрагивал его? И вообще, красит section, а не родителя, странно. Ну и наконец, вероятно, всё решается дополнительным контейнером.

Comment: если элементарно через отладчик добавить цветной фон каждой `section` в твоем коде, то будет видно, что последняя строка секции будет перекрыта фоном секции, идущей за/под ней. так что, во-первых, будет, во-вторых, не "под", а "на", в-третьих, ваще не понял, о чем ты) а красить section как раз таки норм, ибо это контейнер для отдельного блока с инфой, в которой свой заголовок и контент, и значит может быть и свой фон картинкой/цветом

Comment: @lexxl, всё ещё нужен пример. Проблема не воспроизводится. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Ovo.png

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/5CUjM добавил два разных фона и бордер

Comment: @lexxl, можно положить в section div. Можно заменить padding на border.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю данный пример поможет вам (можете подогнать под ваше строение меню)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
$('a').on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var anch = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
var items = $('#'+anch[1]).position().top + 140;
var body = $("html, body");
body.stop().animate({scrollTop:items+'px'}, '800', 'swing');  
console.log(items); 
 }); 
 


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#menu1">Меню 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#menu2">Меню 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#menu3">Меню 3</a></li>
</ul>


<div>
<p id="menu1">Контент</p>
<p id="menu2">Контент</p>
<p id="menu3">Контент</p>
</div>
```

Comment: да якорные ссылки работают отлично, но все остальные совсем не работают, не переходят на нужные странички давал класс всем якорным ссылкам .anchor и писал так и не работает :(( $('a.anchor').on('click',function(e)

Comment: @Ivan разве вам непомог ответ Lexxl , отмеченный как верный ответ?
после установки конкретного класса $('a.anchor') другие ссылки не работают? возможно вам надо очистить старый кеш браузера.

Comment: очистка помогла спасибо)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста )